# Handling user input of * with case in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

i am creating a simple calculator in bash. the user can enter operators "+", "-", "/", and "*".

however, when the user inputs * as an operator, it goes to the final case.
how can i make sure it is correctly interpreted as the multiplication case?

i am new to scripting/unix, although i have prior coding experience. i'm not sure how to handle this without having some if statement in the final case, but i would like to avoid it. thank you

```
case $operator in
                    "+")
                        result=$((operand + next_operand))
                        ;;

                    "-")
                        result=$((operand - next_operand))
                        ;;

                    "*")
                        result=$((operand * next_operand))
                        ;;

                    "/")
                        if [[ $next_operand -eq 0 ]]; then
                            echo "Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor."
                            continue
                        else
                            result=$((operand / next_operand_value))
                        fi
                        ;;

                    *)
                        echo "Invalid operator. Please re-enter operator."
                        continue
                        ;;

                esac
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes... e.g `'*'`

Comment: How exactly do users input the `*` character? Depending on the context, it might be being treated as a wildcard and expanded to a list of filenames.

Comment: @raylight Changing the type of quotes wouldn't make any difference. The code the user shows is correct. The error is in another part of their script, or in the way the input is made to the script, which we know nothing about.

Comment: Immediately before the `case` block you show us, add some debug to check that `$operator` really is what you think it is. `echo "Operator is < $operator >"`. If all's well you'll get `Operator is < * >` but as been suggested above you'll likely be getting a list of filenames instead of the asterisk. At that point you need to look earlier in your code

Comment: thank you everyone for your suggestions.
the input is taken as `read -p "Enter operator: " operator` and i took @ChrisDavies suggestion of adding that debug line, where it prints `Operator is < * >` but then I get `"Sorry, * is not a valid operator. Please re-enter operator.: command not found"`

Comment: The code you're running doesn't match the code you've shown us. In your own code you're missing a double quote somewhere between the line of debug and the error message. Pop the whole lot through https://shellcheck.net and fix the errors it reports

Comment: to inspect the variable use `declare -p operator` -- that will show you any "invisible" characters.

Comment: `read -p "Enter operator: " operator; case $operator in "*") echo an asterisk;; esac` works fine in Bash and with just `read operator`, also in other shells. (Well at least unless you have `IFS` set to contain the asterisk, but you probably don't.)

Comment: show your whole code, [edit] your question

Comment: re-reading the earlier comments, right, the error message you mention getting in the comment isn't something that even exists in the code you show. Showing the wrong code makes it impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want the user to have to munge their input to comport with `BASH` and / or other shell `globbing` standards - that is, to AVOID the `globbing`, then...

If I had this problem, I'd NOT have it done via the command line that launches your calculator but rather prompt the user for input on an on-going basis.

This isn't hard but may be beyond where you presently are with shell scripting. But stick with me here:

Create a function - perhaps call it "prompt."

The function sets a variable.

When an input is received, it's "clean," that is, no shell issues. Whatever the user types, you'll get.

You CAN go character at a time, if you want, or line at a time. I recommend line at a time as a starter exercise.

You simply say "`read <variable>`" where `<variable>` is the name of the variable you want to receive the user's input.

To have text in front of it so the user knows they're being prompted, just add a -p and a string, like this:

```
read -p <prompt-string> <variable>
```

That ought to do it. And of course, you've got to craft it to your needs, but at least your `globbing` problem is gone.

Comment: you can pass `-p <string>` to `bash`'s `read` for prompt.

Comment: @davidt930 That's cool, and I'd ENTIRELY forgotten about it! Thanks!